# how to create new array if condition does not satisfied?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to create array for ids that are part of rxInfo but are not matching with members ids, but its always push memberIds to mismatchIndexIDs.how to check that condition if value is thereand not matching push it to array.

there could be case i will have 4 members in specialMembers and rxInfos only has 2 passed.

main.ts

```
for(const member of specialMembers) {
    for (const rxInfo of this.rxInfos) {
        if (member.indexID === rxInfo.indexID) {
            this.indexIDs.push(rxInfo.indexID);
            proxyMember = member;
            if (!member.dateOfBirth) {
                statusDesc = "member dateOfbirth not found";
                return Promise.reject(this.errorHandler(request, statusDesc));
            }
            const requestBody: any = this.buildSingleRequestBody(proxyMember, rxInfo);
            const requestObject = this.specialtyQuestionRequest(requestBody);
            this.requestArray.push(requestObject);
        } else {
            this.mismatchIndexIDS.push(rxInfo.indexID);
            this.indexIdMismatchCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

data:

```
 "rxInfos": [
      {
            "drugNdc": "10101",
            "rxNumber": "14556459709",
            "firstFillIndicator": "N",
            "sourceSystem": "TBS",
            "indexID": "RPT0ifQ"
        },
      {
            "drugNdc": "101",
            "rxNumber": "145945000709",
            "firstFillIndicator": "N",
            "sourceSystem": "TBS",
            "indexID": "GJhQ1MrQnZkTFRR"
        }
    ]

    "specialyMembers":[
      {
        "dob":"12-12-1970"
        "firstName": "jimmy",
        "lasteName": "shew",
         "indexID": "RPT0ifQ"
      },
      {
         "dob":"18-10-1970"
        "firstName": "Timmy",
        "lasteName": "Doug",
         "indexID": "GJhQ1MrQ"
      },
        {
         "dob":"17-06-1981"
        "firstName": "John",
        "lasteName": "owascar",
         "indexID": "GJhQ1MrTGDSRQ"
      }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over two arrays (O(N^2) operations), transform the first one in a temporary object indexed by the joining key and partition the second array.

```
function partition(arr, predicate) {
    const out = [[],[]];
    arr.forEach(e => out[Number(!!predicate(e))].push(e));
    return out;
}
const membersByIndex = {}
specialMembers.forEach(m => membersByIndex[m.indexID] = m)
const [mismatch, match] = partition(rxInfo, rx => rx.indexID in membersByIndex)
```